# How to check if a PHP list is empty

Tags: php, arrays, list

How to check if a PHP list is empty ?

This clearly doesn't work...

```
list($width, $height) = create_clone($size, $filename, $filepath, $file);

if (!list) {
    echo 'list is filled up with values';
} else {
   echo 'list contains no values';
}
```

Comment: Don't let the name fool you. It isn't actually a list such as you would find in Python or Lisp - it is two distinct variables populated by a language construct.  You would need to either test each individual variable for a value, or test the result of the operation which creates the array.

Comment: First, a list isn't a thing. It doesn't have a name and you can't address it. Second, it can't ever be "empty".

Comment: use `empty()` function.

Comment: Lots of good answers below, **take your pick**. *Pick a card, any card*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list(...) =` is a destructuring assignment operation for arrays. If `$foo = array("one", "two");` then `list ($x, $y) = $foo;` will make `$x` "one" and `$y` "two". When the right side is an expression, then the array in question is a temporary value with no name.

So if you're concerned that `create_clone` might return an empty array you should perhaps *give* the array a name, like:

```
$clone = create_clone($size, $filename, $filepath, $file);
if (empty($clone)) {
  # empty...
} else {
  list($width, $height) = $clone;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`list` isn't just a variable or function, it's a [language construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) filling the variables inside it, you should use something like this:

```
list($width, $height) = create_clone($size, $filename, $filepath, $file);

if (!empty($width) && !empty($height)) {
    echo 'list is filled up with values';
} else {
   echo 'list contains no values';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use !empty

Like so...

```
if (!empty($width) && !empty($height))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tell if `create_clone()` returned an empty result, you need to put the return in a variable of its own:

```
$clone = create_clone($size, $filename, $filepath, $file);
if (!empty($clone)) {
    list($width, $height) = $clone;
    echo 'list is filled up with values';
} else {
    echo 'list contains no values';
}
```